# Python compile all non-words except dot[.]

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to break a line on all non-word patterns except .(dot)
Usually I guess it can be done as [\W ^[.]] in java, but how to I do in python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> the_string="http://hello-world.com"
>>> re.findall(r'[\w.]+',the_string)
['http', 'hello', 'world.com']
```

Comment: Just perfect, Thanks :)
could you explain me this??

Comment: `[\w^[.]]` is for the delimiters, while `[\w.]+` is for the words, thus we call `findall`.

Answer (score 1):

A very good reference for Python's regular expression module is available [here](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html). Following should do the trick for you.

```
import re
re.split(r'[\w.]+', text_string)
```

Or,

```
import re
re.findall('[^\w.]+', text_string)
```

Comment: @Ashish, nope: almost every special character is "disabled" within "sets" (i.e., between brackets) in a pattern, and in particular so is the vertical bar (in its "or" sense which it would have outside brackets).

Comment: @Alex: I remember your post something on the lines of how Python became a part of Google. Excellent read.

Comment: Your regexes work now, but you've got them reversed. The `split` regex should be `[^\w.]+` and the `findall` regex should be `[\w.]+`.

Comment: I felt the OP wants non-words but if words are wanted then yes, they are reversed.

Answer (score 1):

Your Java syntax is off, to begin with.  This is what you were trying for:

```
[\W&&[^.]]
```

That matches a character from the intersection of the sets described by "any non-word character" and "any character except `.`"  But that's overkill when you can just use:

```
[^\w.]
```

...or, "any character that's not a word character or `.`".  It's the same in Python (and in most other flavors, too), though you probably want to match *one or more* of the characters:

```
re.split(r'[^\w.]+', the_string)
```

But it's probably simpler to use @gnibbler's approach of matching the parts that you want to *keep*, not the ones you want to throw away:

```
re.findall(r'[\w.]+', the_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you want to split a string on all non-word patterns except a dot.

Edit: Python doesn't support the Java-style regex syntax that you are using. I'd suggest first replacing all dots with a long string, then splitting the string, then putting the dots back in.

```
import re
long_str = "ABCDEFGH"
str = str.replace('.', long_str)
result = re.split(r'\W', str)
```

Then as you are using `result`, replace all the `long_str` sequences with a dot again.

This is a very bad solution, but it works.

Answer (score -1):

Python has a convenience function for that

```
>>> s = "ab.cd.ef.gh"
>>> s.split(".")
['ab', 'cd', 'ef', 'gh']
```

Comment: And how does that help the OP with "all non-word patterns except dot"?!  This splits by dot only -- poles apart from what the OP asked.

Comment: D'oh! Poles apart indeed. Haven't had my coffee yet. Sorry about that.